# How I can speed up the build process using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Maven as build tool. Presently I am building using this command.

*Right click on the project* > *Maven clean*.

After this:

*Right click on the project* > *Maven install*

It is taking 3 minutes for me. Is there any way to speed up my process?

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161698/how-can-i-speed-up-my-maven2-build). But I did not understand this. Can any one hep me?

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.test.test:TEST:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.metaparadigm:json-rpc:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 1.0 @ line 323, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 39, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 25, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin is missing. @ line 18, column 11
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.groupId' for log4j:log4j:jar is missing. @ line 356, column 18
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for log4j:log4j:jar is missing. @ line 356, column 18
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test Web 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.Test.Test:Test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.Test.Test:Test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of wso2-maven2-repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.Test.Test:Test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
Downloading: http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/commons-collections/commons-collections/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata commons-collections:commons-collections/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata commons-collections:commons-collections/maven-metadata.xml from/to jasperreports (http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal): connection timed out to http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/commons-collections/commons-collections/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Documents and Settings\ITGRIDS\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml is invalid: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...www.sermonillustrationlibrary.org/blocked/nospiders?mod=8819&qlvc=... @467:198) 
Downloading: http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/commons-digester/commons-digester/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata commons-digester:commons-digester/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata commons-digester:commons-digester/maven-metadata.xml from/to jasperreports (http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal): connection timed out to http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/commons-digester/commons-digester/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Documents and Settings\ITGRIDS\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml is invalid: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...www.sermonillustrationlibrary.org/blocked/nospiders?mod=8819&qlvc=... @425:221) 
Downloading: http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/commons-logging/commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata commons-logging:commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata commons-logging:commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml from/to jasperreports (http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal): connection timed out to http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/commons-logging/commons-logging/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Documents and Settings\ITGRIDS\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml is invalid: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...www.sermonillustrationlibrary.org/blocked/nospiders?mod=8819&qlvc=... @446:198) 
Downloading: http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/com/lowagie/itext/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.lowagie:itext/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.lowagie:itext/maven-metadata.xml from/to jasperreports (http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal): connection timed out to http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/com/lowagie/itext/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Documents and Settings\ITGRIDS\.m2\repository\com\lowagie\itext\maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml is invalid: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...www.sermonillustrationlibrary.org/blocked/nospiders?mod=8819&qlvc=... @425:221) 
Downloading: http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/jfree/jcommon/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata jfree:jcommon/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata jfree:jcommon/maven-metadata.xml from/to jasperreports (http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal): connection timed out to http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/jfree/jcommon/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Documents and Settings\ITGRIDS\.m2\repository\jfree\jcommon\maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml is invalid: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...www.sermonillustrationlibrary.org/blocked/nospiders?mod=8819&qlvc=... @443:198) 
Downloading: http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/jfree/jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata jfree:jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata jfree:jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml from/to jasperreports (http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal): connection timed out to http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/jfree/jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/eclipse/jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata eclipse:jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata eclipse:jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml from/to jasperreports (http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal): connection timed out to http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/eclipse/jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Documents and Settings\ITGRIDS\.m2\repository\eclipse\jdtcore\maven-metadata-jaspersoft.xml is invalid: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...www.sermonillustrationlibrary.org/blocked/nospiders?mod=8819&qlvc=... @435:198) 
Downloading: http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/javax/servlet/servlet-api/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata javax.servlet:servlet-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/): No connector available to access repository wso2-maven2-repository (scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/maven2/) of type default using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata javax.servlet:servlet-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to jasperreports (http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal): connection timed out to http://escidoc1.escidoc.mpg.de:8888/archiva/repository/internal/javax/servlet/servlet-api/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] The artifact jstl:jstl:jar:1.1.2 has been relocated to javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Test ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 23 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Test ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 384 source files to D:\TEST\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ Test ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

Comment: It all depends on how big your project is and how fast the repository you're connecting to and whether you've force enabled the SNAPSHOTS to be downloaded on every build.

Comment: can you post logs while your are running maven

Comment: @asgs how i can prevent dowloading every time

Comment: here i have so many logs.Which i need to post

Comment: @shreyanshjogi see i posted logs generated

Comment: I'm referring to this piece where [downloading Snapshot dependencies could be configured](http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-testing-development-plugins.html#Using_Settings_without_Modifying_the_Project), but I highly recommend to keep it enabled to take the latest available changes.

Comment: @PSR refer https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-maven-build-is-slow-speed-it-up/

Answer (score 21):

If you're using multiple maven modules within a project, this might work for you: I'm using Maven mostly via console, so I have no experience with this under eclipse, but as of Maven 3, Maven supports parallel builds. This feature works out of the box, but its success depends a lot on the plugins you use, as 3rd party plugins might not be designed to work that way.

To activate parallel builds, start maven with the `-T` parameter:

```
mvn clean install -T 2
```

builds with 2 threads.

```
mvn clean install -T 2C
```

builds with 2 threads per CPU.

Maven will determine a build order and parallelize as much as possible.

Sadly, if your project module structure is very linear, ie project A --> project B --> project C, this won't do you any good.

Answer (score 1):

If your project has test cases you can skip your test by following command.

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Answer (score 0):

just try to avoid downloading every time 
Execute Maven in offline mode to avoid downloading of dependencies everytime your build is run.

If you are using command line you can use -o as an argument.

Comment: edit your pom.xml
<repository>
<id>central</id>
<url>file://D:\mavenrepo</url> at place or url put local repo path


</repository>

Comment: r u saying about m2 folder path

Comment: @PSR: You can also check offline checkbox available below the profiles textbox.